# when reorg rebuild table was executed?

Tags: sql, sybase

There was a reorg rebuild on a table,

`Reorg rebuild EX_EMPLOYEE`

can I know the date when this reorg rebuild happened ? a date like `01-01-2017`

this query
`select * from sysobjects where name='EX_EMPLOYEE'` will give me when the table created. it doesnt contains info about reorg

Answer (score 0):

the below helped me

select name, id, crdate from sysindexes where id = object_id('EX_EMPLOYEE')